# Eclipse : Project properties don't show Build Path

Tags: eclipse, build, classpath

My Eclipse does not show the 'Java Build Path' option in my Java project's properties. The properties screenshot is attached below. What might be the reason for this? On the left side there should be an option for 'Java Build Path'.

[image: Build path not available]

Comment: See this as well [Adding Builders to Project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434400/adding-builders-to-project-in-eclipse-and-incremental-ness)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse adding your own build command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976610/eclipse-adding-your-own-build-command)

Comment: Select the project -> 'Properties' -> 'Java Build Path' [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdWEA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdWEA.png) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYNYn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYNYn.png)

Comment: Similar issue answered in below post https://stackoverflow.com/a/59519099/7434392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get some help from any of these blogs

[How do I add a builder to a given project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_a_builder_to_a_given_project?)

OR check this post

[Eclipse adding your own build command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976610/eclipse-adding-your-own-build-command)

Answer (score 43):

To resolve this issue follow the below options

1) Go to Project **root** 
2) Select "**Project facets**" from **Properties**
3) Check "**Java**"

This fixes the issue

Comment: Excellent, to the point answer, thank you so much...                                  Right click the project-> Properties -> Select Project Facets -> Click Convert to faceted form... -> In Project Facets an option with Java would be preselected (if not select Java ) -> Finally click OK

Comment: Option Java is not existed.. so how..?

Comment: Did not had hope, but tried :P and it worked.

Answer (score 13):

I was in the same situation, and found two different solutions for this.

1. Right click on the `src` folder and check if you can see the option to configure the build path. After that, right click on the project and do Maven > update project.

If this does not work,

2. Right click on the project >  properties > project facets and click on the link saying convert the project into faceted project.

Right click on the project, hit Refresh and check if you get the option to configure build path now.

Comment: This was a life saver, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to compile a project. The solution was to go to "run configurations" and choose the right Runtime JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Build your project using **Project->Build Project** in Eclipse .This will automatically adds build path to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete my maven .m2/repository folder and that made my build path reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project's root directory contains `.classpath` and `.project` file.

1. The `.classpath` file should look like this -

[image]

2. The `.project` file should look like this -

[image]

With these changes in place you should be able to see the proper folder structure as well as the "Build Path" option when you right-click the project.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working fine previously and now its not, check whether you are in Enterprise tab or the Navigator tab, because if you're in the Navigator tab it won't work.